# how to set up laravel cron job in cpanel?

Tags: php, laravel, cron

In my local system cron job is working perfectly when calling php artisan schedule:run. but when i upload laravel project into my cpanel, the cron job is not working. Below is my cpanel cron job path.

```
*   *   *   *   *   php -d register_argc_argv=On /home/techworld/public_html/hubli-betting/artisan schedule:run > /dev/null 2>&1
```

This command generates below mention error in log file.

```
[2019-12-19 15:15:03] local.ERROR: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() at /home/techworld/public_html/hubli-betting/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php:246)
[stacktrace]
#0 /home/techworld/public_html/hubli-betting/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php(246): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'Invalid argumen...', '/home/techworld...', 246, Array)
#1 /home/techworld/public_html/hubli-betting/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(1060): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput->getFirstArgument()
#2 /home/techworld/public_html/hubli-betting/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(81): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->getCommandName(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput))
#3 /home/techworld/public_html/hubli-betting/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(133): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#4 /home/techworld/public_html/hubli-betting/artisan(36): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#5 {main}
"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine in crontab, you can try this:

```
$ crontab -e
```

Then add this line into the file.

```
* * * * * cd /var/www/html/YOUR_PROJECT && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Check whether addition was successful using:

```
$ crontab -l
```

Answer (score 0):

Mine is working using the following:

```
***** cd /home/techworld/public_html/hubli-betting && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

[image]